# Load Components dynamically from JSON and render it in HTML

Tags: typescript, angular8, angular9

I have a content JSON, which has custom angular components. What I want to achieve is being able to extract from that JSON the content and display it.

Sample JSON

```
{
"contentContainer": {
    "contentList": {
        "Home_Div_1": {
            "refId": "Home_Div_1",
            "content": "<title-component> Hi there </title-component>"
        },
        "Home_Div_2": {
            "refId": "Home_Div_2",
            "content": "<desc-component> Description section </desc-component>"
        }
    }
}
```

}

So the HTML page should be like

```
 <title-component> Hi there </title-component>
<desc-component> Description section </desc-component>
```

[Applying all the component level styles etc ]

I have tried inner HTML with dom sanitiser etc which works fine if only HTML tags are used, not for custom angular components.
The problem is the string extracted from the JSON needs to be transformed and be rendered as a custom angular component like if it were not coming from the JSON but a module itself.
I have tried  - but the problem here is it does not we dont receive a html, but a string.

Newbie here, any help in the right direction will be helpful

Comment: Maybe [this](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) can help you, but I think you might have overcomplicated this, what is your use case?

Comment: So all the content on the page is referenced from a JSON, so in the HTML I mention <app-content id="Home_Div_1"></app-content> so in the JSON the content with that Id should be rendered, in this case <title-component> Hi there </title-component>" with title component having its own set of styling etc.

Comment: I have tried dynamic component loading, but in that case -  you have to render only the data coming from the service, in my case it's not just the data, its the webpage structure itself, which will be different for different pages

Comment: @NidhiRanjan  bringing content,style with HTML tags etc from backend and pushing inside angular DOM has various security issues. Generally Angular DOM sanitizer, sanitizes all incoming data to prevent any potential xss attack. Its good practice to make templates in Angular and use them wherever required.